# jQuery.getJSON() not working on page load. Works fine inside a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, getjson

I'm making a "show-you-local-wather-app"(freecodecamp), and I want it to get the data on page load. But nothing happens. I quite new at this so I'm wondering if I've missed something obvious.

It works just fine if I put it inside $("#some_button").on("click", etc...

I've tried putting it inside $(document).ready without any succes. What am I missing here?

```
var latitude, longitude;
var apiKey = "9b6a0d53a4ed3ff657c6ff6e18ffa42f";
var url;

function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    latitude = crd.latitude;
    longitude = crd.longitude;
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&units=metric&appid=" + apiKey;
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

// AJAX call

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $("#location").html(data.name + ", " + data.sys.country);
    $("#weather_type").html(data.weather[0].description);
    var imgURL = data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
    $("#icon").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + imgURL + "'>");
    $("#deg").html(data.main.temp);
    $("#windspeed").html(data.wind.speed);
    console.log(data);
});
```

I've made it with [codepen](http://codepen.io/developingMike/pen/PNJVyp) if anyone want to see it.
I'm using the [OpenWeatherMap API](http://openweathermap.org/current).

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a `)` to close your `.fail()` call

Comment: The geolocation call is asynchronous and does not return immediately. Your "url" isn't ready at the point you make the `$.getJSON()` call.

Comment: i have played around few month ago with it. here is my example: http://codepen.io/7urkm3n/pen/JGJpXa

Comment: @micheal, It was working all your functions. Just that `navigator` function callback takes time, when successfully responses then triggering AJAX. So, if user has slow internet he will wait until success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is better solution, If your `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)` successfully returns then run `runner()` function.

Here is quite simple examples [Cordova Doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/cordova/geolocation/geolocation.getCurrentPosition.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var latitude, longitude;
var apiKey = "9b6a0d53a4ed3ff657c6ff6e18ffa42f";
var url;

function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    latitude = crd.latitude;
    longitude = crd.longitude;
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&units=metric&appid=" + apiKey;

    runner(url);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

// AJAX call
 function runner(url){
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

    $("#location").html(data.name + ", " + data.sys.country);
    $("#weather_type").html(data.weather[0].description);
    var imgURL = data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
    $("#icon").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + imgURL + "'>");
    $("#deg").html(data.main.temp);
    $("#windspeed").html(data.wind.speed);
    console.log(data);
  });
}; //end of runner

}); //end of document.ready
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code issues the `$.getJSON` call before you've got the coordinates in hand. You need to wait until you have the coordinates, and *then* fire the ajax call. Notice where `ajaxCall` gets invoked in the code below:

```
var latitude, longitude;
var apiKey = "9b6a0d53a4ed3ff657c6ff6e18ffa42f";
var url;

function ajaxCall(url) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var imgURL = data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
    $("#location").html(data.name + ", " + data.sys.country);
    $("#weather_type").html(data.weather[0].description);
    $("#icon").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + imgURL + "'>");
    $("#deg").html(data.main.temp);
    $("#windspeed").html(data.wind.speed);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    latitude = crd.latitude;
    longitude = crd.longitude;
    url = (
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" +
        "?lat=" + latitude + 
        "&lon=" + longitude + 
        "&units=metric" +
        "&appid=" + apiKey
    )
    ajaxCall(url);
  }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
});
```

It's sitting inside of the `success` function—so it can't fire until the data is available.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did it like this and now it works. I guess in principle it's the same as the answer from 7urkm3n?

```
function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    getPos(crd.latitude, crd.longitude);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

function getPos(latitude, longitude) {
    var apiKey = "9b6a0d53a4ed3ff657c6ff6e18ffa42f";
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&units=metric&appid=" + apiKey;

    // AJAX call
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $("#location").html(data.name + ", " + data.sys.country);
        $("#weather_type").html(data.weather[0].description);
        var imgURL = data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
        $("#icon").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + imgURL + "'>");
        $("#deg").html(data.main.temp);
        $("#windspeed").html(data.wind.speed);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess to why $.ready doesn't work, when the DOM is ready, $.getJSON is still fetching from the external API.

But here's an alternative

**Using setInterval**

To stop it after running a set number of times, just add a counter to the interval, then when it reached that number it stops.

```
var latitude, longitude;
var apiKey = "9b6a0d53a4ed3ff657c6ff6e18ffa42f";
var url;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    latitude = crd.latitude;
    longitude = crd.longitude;
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&units=metric&appid=" + apiKey;
});

// AJAX call
var timesRun = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    timesRun += 1;
    if(timesRun === 2){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $("#location").html(data.name + ", " + data.sys.country);
        $("#weather_type").html(data.weather[0].description);
        var imgURL = data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
        $("#icon").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + imgURL + "'>");
        $("#deg").html(data.main.temp);
        $("#windspeed").html(data.wind.speed);
        console.dir(data);
    });
}, 2000);
```